# NSPoint/NSRect from character in NSTextView

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

So I am trying to get either an NSPoint or NSRect corresponding with the location of a specific character in an NSTextView. This is what I have so far (that isn't working very well, the results seem kind of unpredictable.

```
NSRange theTextRange = [[theTextView layoutManager] glyphRangeForCharacterRange:[theTextStorage editedRange] actualCharacterRange:NULL];
NSRect theTextRect = [[theTextView layoutManager] boundingRectForGlyphRange:theTextRange inTextContainer:[theTextView textContainer]];
```

Answer (score 7):

The rect returned by `boundingRectForGlyphRange:inTextContainer:` is in container coordinates. You need to adjust for this if you want to get the rect relative to the text view:

```
NSRange theTextRange = [[textView layoutManager] glyphRangeForCharacterRange:textRange actualCharacterRange:NULL];
NSRect layoutRect = [[textView layoutManager] boundingRectForGlyphRange:theTextRange inTextContainer:[textView textContainer]];
NSPoint containerOrigin = [textView textContainerOrigin];
layoutRect.origin.x += containerOrigin.x;
layoutRect.origin.y += containerOrigin.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mouse down event by NSPoint & NSRect

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface ClickTextView : NSView {
    NSMutableArray *texts;
    NSPoint currentLocation;
    NSCell *cell;
}

@end

#import "ClickTextView.h"
@interface TextClip : NSObject
{

@public
    NSString *text;
    NSPoint location;
}

@end

@implementation TextClip @end


@implementation ClickTextView
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    texts = [NSMutableArray new];
    cell = [[NSTextFieldCell alloc] initTextCell: @""];
    [cell setEditable: YES];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect 
{
    NSRect frame = rect;
    [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect: rect];
    for (TextClip *clip in texts)
    {
        [cell setStringValue: clip->text];
        frame.origin = clip->location;
        [cell drawWithFrame: frame inView: self];
    }
}

- (void)mouseDown: (NSEvent*)theEvent
{
    currentLocation = [self convertPoint: [theEvent locationInWindow]
                                fromView: nil];
    NSText *fieldEditor = [[self window] fieldEditor: YES
                                           forObject: self];
    [cell endEditing: fieldEditor];
    [fieldEditor setString: @""];
    [cell setStringValue: @""];
    NSRect frame = {currentLocation, {400, 400}};
    [cell editWithFrame: frame
                 inView: self
                 editor: fieldEditor
               delegate: self
                  event: theEvent];
}
- (BOOL)isFlipped
{
    return YES;
}
- (void)textDidEndEditing: (NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSText *text = [aNotification object];
    TextClip *clip = [[TextClip alloc] init];
    clip->text = [[text string] copy];
    clip->location = currentLocation;
    [texts addObject: clip];
    [cell endEditing: text];
    [self setNeedsDisplay: YES];
}
@end
```