# mouse coordinates in NSScrollView

Tags: macos, graphics

I have NSImageView inside NSScrollView on MAC. I subclass NSImageView and capture mouse down event.

But the coordinates keep changing depending if the NSScrollView is panned or zoomed even if I click on the same point in image.

How can I get a consistent mouse coordinate when zoomed or panned, here is my non working code.

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSPoint currentLocation = [theEvent locationInWindow];
    NSPoint locationInView = [scrollView convertPoint:currentLocation fromView:self];
    [super mouseDown:theEvent];
}
```

Anybody???

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and found the answer 
[in this stack overflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028775/converting-an-nspoint-from-window-coordinates-to-view-coordinates)

```
NSPoint aLocationInSelf = [self convertPoint: [anEvent locationInWindow] fromView: nil];
```